# How to get the Facebook Login Button Image for IOS UIButton?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

How to get default Facebook image for UIButton image ?

[image]

I don't want to use FBLoginView, but I need the exact images used in FBLoginView. Could someone help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

If the Facebook API permits, why not just use the button code in your app? Otherwise, you could easily recreate this button by adding a UIImageView to the button for the Facebook logo and then setting the UIButton's titleLabel to that exact text (you could even add a UILabel over it if you wanted to get ore exact control over the frame).

Comment: I am in a confusion on how to use FBLoginView with Parse for Login and Logout in my Application. I saw their tutorial and it basically shows how it works with single view, but I want it to work for My Application Login. Could you explain it how to use ?

Comment: Sounds like there's a lot going on here. I believe I offered a solution to your original question. Try posting your new questions in another post, since your original post here specifically stated that you didn't want to use FBLoginView.

Answer (score 0):

Use the facebook button , provided by facebook hide this in UI , then trigger this button using your custom  image as a button.